# drupal custom moduel(Jquery Effect)

Tags: drupal

hi i have to make a jquery image plugin in drupal. i have made the code in core php but don't have any idea how can i integrate in the drupal. if any one have any idea about this or any kind of suggestion regarding this, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, because Drupal is modular based, the most obvious thing to do would be creating your own custom Drupal module. And in that module you'd include the necessary javascript files,php files,etc...

there's a developer handbook for creating modules
http://drupal.org/developing/modules

the Drupal api has it's own functions, variables,etc.. which can be useful. Consider Drupal as a framework if you will, so if you want to follow the guidelines and code conventions when creating a module, your base code can require some changes.

oh and keep in mind that a basic Drupal installation has jQuery 1.2 installed. so if your jQuery code needs a more recent version, you should install the jquery update module (http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) first.

Hopefully you can get on your way now ;)